# Extremal points and mixture

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis

I have a set of probability measures $\mathcal{I}$ on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ and a family $\mathcal{F} = \{\mu_\alpha: \alpha \in [0,1]\} \subset \mathcal{I}$. The set $\mathcal{I}$ is compact and convex. I proved that for every $\mu \in \mathcal{I}$ there exists a distribution $\gamma$ in $[0,1]$ such that
$$\mu = \int^1_0 \mu_\alpha \gamma(d\alpha).$$
If $\nu$ is an extremal measure of $\mathcal{I}$, I want to prove that $\nu \in \mathcal{F}$.

This integral is related to the notion of mixture ([Generalized notions of mixture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141744/generalized-notions-of-mixture)). If I would have a finite mixture (finite convex sum) it is straightforward but in this case, I have an "infinite" convex sum. Approximation to finite measures didn't work. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Presumably $\mathcal{I}$ is a convex set of probability measures? Looks like something from [Choquet's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory).

Comment: Yes! I missed some information. Convex and compact.